# "npm version <major|minor|patch>" and the "dist" directory

Tags: node.js, git, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-header

I am using `node.js` along with `gulp` as an infrastructure for my environment. I am using this environment to write a jQuery plugin. The directory structure looks like this:

```
jquery-plugin
    |
    ---- dist (contains complied and minified plugin files)
    |
    ---- src (source code)
    |
    ---- gulpfile.js
    |
    ---- package.json
```

Now, I have written my `gulp` file to contain instructions to contain a `watch` task, that will copy files from `src` to `dist` whenever a change is saved. Also note that the banner in the header section of the `js` files is set through `gulp-header`, which includes version number that is automatically pulled from `package.json`

So far everything is correct.

Now, assuming I start with version **0.0.1**, and go through a development cycle (which is done in my `develop` branch), then eventually my code is ready. I would commit everything in my `develop` branch, then switch to `master`, merge the code from `develop`. Now code is ready to be published.

I would go to my terminal, and run `npm version minor`. This would make the version **0.1.0** and check in a new version to `master`, and add tag **v0.1.0**. The problem is, the files in `src` and `dist` will still have version **0.0.1** in their header (which were pulled from the *previous* version, before running the version command, because no actually saving in those files has been made after running the version command).

How do I ensure that the version is automatically updated in the header section of `js` files in the `dist` directory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigating the issue, I did the following:

1. Run `npm --no-git-tag-version version minor`. This would bump the version, but would not check in any files nor add tags.
2. Touch/save one of the `src` files. This will update the header with the correct version number in the `dist` directory
3. Manually check-in in git, and add a new tag in the format `vMa.Mi.P` (where `Mi` is the **major** number, `Mi` is the **minor** number, and `P` is the **patch** number)

Reference: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version